# Observing gVim console output on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, stdout, stderr

I am attempting to debug a misbehaving Vim plug-in that is apparently writing stuff to stdout and stderr, but since gVim seems to launch in a separate process when run from the command line, I have to way to inspect it.  Is there any solution?

Comment: How do you know it's writing stuff to stdout and stderr if you can't inspect it?

Comment: The plugin is YouCompleteMe, and despite having followed the instructions on the Wiki to the letter, I am getting the following error:

`The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with :YcmRestartServer). Stderr (last 30 line s)`

It seems like there should be something printing to stderr (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ycm-users/l-d6Wfe-kgk).

Comment: It's a YCM issue, use their (overloaded) issue tracker.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to use their issue tracker, but I see many many people have reported the same generic error message, and are only greeted with the reply "Please read CONTRIBUTING.md"  I would like to find out some additional information so that a) hopefully I can fix the problem myself, or b) I can give a useful issue report that is likely to get addressed.  Seeing as inspecting the stderr/stdout seems like a general Vim/Windows issue, I thought it better to ask here (I will give Ingo's reply a shot when I get home).

Comment: YCM uses a server (ycmd), it's probably that server that spits out errors which would make Vim a red herring, here. That server is what you need to monitor.

Comment: Hmm, probably.  I did try to track down the log files but ran into more problems (the command to print the location of the log files doesn't work when the server has crashed), hence my attempt to get the stdout.  But that is indeed a problem for the YMC tracker.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's hard to write to stdout / stderr from Vimscript, I doubt that this is what the plugin does.

In any way, hardly any plugin is GVIM-only, so you can just launch terminal Vim to capture the output.

#### debugging tips

To troubleshoot the misbehaving plugin, I recommend to capture a verbose log with `vim -V20vimlog`.

If that doesn't suffice, you can step through the plugin, e.g. with `:breakadd file plugin/pluginname.vim`. Finally, don't hesitate to contact the plugin's author; he's best suited to help you.